# Django - Can't do a POST request, receiving 405 "Method not allowed"

Tags: python, django, http

i'm trying to do a simple POST request to my endpoint, but i'm getting a 405 "Method not Allowed", here's my code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/exemplo/post/$', ExempleView.as_view(), name='post'),
]
```

Post method:

```
class ExempleView(APIView):

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            print(request.data)
```

Server logs:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /api/exemplos/post/
[29/Apr/2017 14:30:20] "POST /api/exemplos/post/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

I'm using Postman to do the post request and rest_framework to create my API, any suggestion?

Comment: You are not returning a response in ``post``.

Comment: If you're trying to POST a form, have you included the csrf_token?

Comment: I disabled the csrf token to use JWT @Mashakal

Comment: @Grimmy I've changed here and added a response, but i'm getting 405 again

Comment: @MateusLuiz Then update the code in the question

Comment: What is this `APIView`? If it's not something that you wrote it could have overridden the `http_method_names` attribute to exclude `POST`.

Comment: @MateusLuiz in `r'^api/exemplo/post/$'` you are missing an 's' at exemplo, is this a typo? If not fix it on your code!